# What determines the dimensions of the screen grid in OpenGL ES 2.0? (using C++)

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using some demos that came with my OpenGL ES emulator as a starting point. The demo I'm currently using is 960x540 pixels with a simple 2D triangle drawn in the middle of the screen.

I see that the triangle has been drawn with floats, and that the lower-left corner of the screen is (-1,-1) while the upper-right corner of the screen is (1,1).

Is it possible to change this? I would like to use integers instead of floats, and have the lower-left corner of the screen be (1,1) while the upper-right corner is (960,540).

This would be much easier to work with because I plan to make a 2D platformer game. I do not want to split any pixels in this game; everything (textures, player movement, camera movement) will conform to whole-pixel coordinates.

I tried crunching the numbers (using the regular grid and floats) to draw a right triangle that was 24x24 pixels. However, it ended up being 24x23 pixels on the screen. So I didn't want to continue going forward if there was a more accurate, faster method that could use pixel coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values coming out of the vertex shader should be ready for projection into the normal OpenGL eye space, but you needn't pass in vertices in that space. In ES 1 you'd have adjusted the projection stack; does your demo have any analogue to that?

You should also take the filling rules into account. A pixel is always filled if its centre is within the geometry; if its centre is on the boundary then the implementation will make a decision usually depending on which boundary the pixel is on — the top, bottom, left or right boundaries (which make more sense if you think in terms of the pixel output; so a pixel on the left boundary is one that would be first on a scanline, a pixel on the right would be last, a pixel on the top would start the polygon further up the screen, a pixel on the bottom would extend it further down).

The aim is that OpenGL doesn't draw pixels twice where geometry meets on an edge.

With that in mind, a triangle can be exactly 24 pixel units tall but if it runs from the centre of one pixel to the centre of another it will paint only [at most] 23 rows. So your maths may already be correct. Consider one polygon from y = 0 to y = 24 and one from y = 24 to y = 36 — you don't want them both painting at y = 24, especially as they may be partially transparent.

Comment: The demo does have a 4x4 matrix with the comment: "Matrix used for projection model view". It has 1's in a diagonal line going down, with zeros everywhere else. What numbers would you recommend I put in there?

Comment: Thinking as I type, I guess you want to scale x by 2/960, so put that in the top left, y by 2/540 so put that next along the main diagonal, then you want to shift the centre to the bottom left so that's negative on x and negative on y, by -1 in each case, so those would go in the top two positions in the final column. In standard GL terms, as an array that'd be {2.0f/960.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f/540.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}

Comment: Just tried out your matrix and it works perfectly. Now all the shapes I draw end up exactly where I expect them to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can apply an appropriate transform using an orthogonal projection matrix with extents set to your resolution.

How to make such matrices: http://db-in.com/blog/2011/04/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/

Applying this transform in the vertex shader, allows you to directly supply pixel coords in vertex data.

The tricky part is, that pixels (the *center* of them) aren't located at whole numbers in this case!
This is where things usually get odd => an appropriate search term may be 'pixel perfect OpenGL'.

Adding `0.5` to pixel coordinates in the vertex shader, which then can be supplied as whole numbers, should do the trick. Note, that in the vertex shader, you have to convert integer vertex coords to float, if floats are passed, you should round() them before.

If you want to supply normalized coordinates, {-1,-1} - { 1,1 } as you do it now (I don't recommend that):

```
vec2 pixelSize         = 2.0 / vec2(viewportWidth,viewportHeight);
vec2 halfPixelSize     = 1.0 / vec2(viewportWidth,viewportHeight);
vec2 pixelPerfectCoord = round(coord,pixelSize) + halfPixelSize
```

Comment: What helps to make sense of the oddness is to think of OpenGL coordinates as a _continuous_ space (floats rather than ints). Pixels are little squares, and integer coordinates fall _between_ pixels. It's like the ticks on a ruler, where the pixels are the spaces between the ticks.

Comment: Hitting the pixels in the center makes perfect sense now that I think about it. The link you provided also has a very useful image for understanding projection matrices (image with the caption: "Visual representation of a Matrix 4x4 and a Quaternion."). Thanks for the answers.